# How to expand a component to the bottom of the page and make it eventually scrollable?

Tags: html, css

I would like to expand a component's height until the bottom of the page is reached. Eventually, a scrollbar should appear inside it, depending on the content, but the page doesn't have to scroll, only the component itself should be scrollable.

The solution I found so far is the following:

```
<div style="height: 83vh; overflow-y: auto;">
    <div class="container-fluid pt-3">
       <div class="card-columns">
          <div class="card" style="max-width:250px;" *ngFor="let myImg of imgList">
              <img class="card-img-top" style="width:100%;" [src]="myImg">
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which is not the perfect solution, because that `height: 83vh;` may depend by the browser and work well only in my case. I then tried doing the following:

```
<div style="height: 100%; overflow-y: auto;">
```

but the div would overflow the web page, activating the page scroll and not the component scroll.

Any suggestion to achieve the behavior I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can play around with the `calc()` function in CSS; you can take into account the full `viewport height` and substract the amount in px equal to other components in the screen, so that the component you want to fill the screen with only uses that remaining space.

If you test the snippet; the component uses enough space depending on the content inside, but if the content grows large enough to push the component to the bottom, instead of causing the whole page to scroll, it stays in place and only scrolls the content inside.

```css
/* These styles are just for consistency */

body {
  margin: 0;
}

body * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/*****************************************/

.top-bar {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: black;
}

section .component {
  max-height: calc(100vh - 60px);
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-bar">
</div>
<section>
  <div class="component">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>

    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>

    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>

    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>

    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>

  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: This is probably the easiest way to achieve what I want. I played around the calc() function and I found the parameters I need to get what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned in one of your comments that you're using Angular - you should update the question to include that and add it as a tag.

You can use window.innerHeight to get the pixel height of the current view.

If you have a singleton service in your Angular application where you're maintaining state, you can use a Behavior Subject to store that value so you can observe it in your components:

```
ie: state.service.ts 

import { Observable, Subject, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

  // Observable number sources
  private currentWindowHeightStore = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);

  // Observable number streams
  public currentWindowHeight$ = this.currentWindowHeightStore.asObservable();

  // Service message commands
  public setCurrentWindowHeight(WindowHeight: number) {
    this.currentWindowHeightStore.next(WindowHeight);
  }
```

Then in your component, define variables to store the windowSize, and if you're using pageable content (a list of items), a variable to store the pageSize:

```
  private windowSize: number;
  private pageSize: number;
```

In ngOnInit in your component, subscribe to the state.service Observable, and set the windowSize and pageSize based on the total window size, less any space required for navigation etc. (I've used sample values here, you'll want to set them according to your own layouts)

```
this.stateSvc.currentWindowHeight$
.subscribe(
  (windowSize => {
    this.windowSize = windowSize;
    this.pageSize = Math.round((this.windowSize - 200) / 30) - 2;
    this.cvPaging.pageSize = this.pageSize;
    this.flex.refresh(true);
    // 200 is the total size of the navigation header if you have one
    // 30 is the size of a single row in the grid
    // Total window size - minus total navigation / divided by the row height gives us the number of rows
    // that will fit on the current screen size and we set the paging parameter to that value - 2 rows
  }))
```

Now you have a windowSize variable that will update whenever the browser window changes size, and a pageSize variable that you can use if you're paging long lists to know how many items will fit in the window at it's current size.

You can use the windowSize variable to set the height of your container div with ngStyle:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'height': 'auto','max-height':windowSize}>
    Your content here.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The style property you are looking for is `max-height`. You can set this on your div and it will keep it from ever growing larger than that.

One trick for viewing this `max-height` in the event that you currently don't have enough content to fill it to maximum is to set the `height` equal to the `max-height` (temporarily) and to also temporarily give yourself a `border` on the div. This will allow you to visualize just how big that div can get.

**EDIT: Different approach... (With fiddle example):**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Then, make the height of your main div a percentage, 100% will make it absolutely to the bottom, you may not like the look of this so try 95%, add `overflow: auto;` to get a scrollbar whenever the height is greater than the container it is in.

[See Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/hhaag18/t7gup8d0/8/)

Comment: That makes sense, but how do I know which is the right value I should place in the max-height property? Because currently my problem is not having not enough content but having too much content so that the component overflows the page. I think what I want is to put the max-height of my component to be equal to the remaining space in the page. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Are you saying you want the `max-height` to be dynamic, different for every person depending on their resolution/height of their monitor? Or, are you saying the child div is overflowing past the `max-height` of the parent div even with a `max-height` set?

Comment: Yes, I want the max-height to be dynamic, depending on the screen. It should reach the bottom of the page (so the page is not scrollable) and display (or not display) a inner scrollbar in the component if needed.

Comment: Try the following instead, let me know how it works. `html, body { height: 100%; }`

Comment: It doesn't. If it may help, I am inside an Angular component which should expand to the bottom and show the scroll inside it, depending on its content.

Comment: Okay, new approach. I tried something out for myself on a small test site and it worked for me (famous last words)... I am editing my answer, please let me know how it works for you.

Comment: @Rexam I added a fiddle for what im talking about, see that and let me know if it works for what you need